# 403 Forbidden after 10 POSTs

Tags: entities, authentication-authorization

**Problem/Motivation**

Repeated posting a redhen_contact via the Drupal JSON:API succeeds for exactly 10 times in a row. The 11th attempt fails with 403 status code.
After waiting for 60-120 seconds, the next 10 POSTs succeed again.

BasicAuth is used, user account has the necessary permissions, also affects user 1.
Strangely, this happens with the redhen_contact entity type only, entities of type redhen_organization or redhen_connection are not affected.
Drupal core 9.5.9
RedHen CRM 2.0.0-rc1, same behavior with 8.x-1.0

Any hints what the cause of this strange problem could be are highly appreciated!

**Steps to reproduce**

POST with postman or any other client, 11 times
Request header:
'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json',
'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json'

Example request body:

```javascript
{"data": {
    "type": "redhen_contact--crm_cont_pers", 
    "attributes": {
      "first_name": "John", 
      "middle_name": null, 
      "last_name": "Smith", 
      "email": null
    }
  }
 }
```

Response on request #1-10:

201 Created

Response on request #11:

403 Forbidden

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Is this problem exhibited on all platforms? It's possibly unrelated to Drupal.

Comment: Possibly the flood module? Do you have flooding rules on the server otherwise?

Comment: @Kevin No, i have'nt installed the flood module

Comment: @cliefen Do you mean other hosting platforms? It happens only with one entity type, other types work well - So i suspect it is related to Drupal